# Connecting to MySQL database with visual studio 2012

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2012

I use visual studio 2012 and I downloaded an extension to be able to make a connection to a MySQL database.

The installation is successful, but when I try to write the authentication data in the database (server, user, pass etc..), The window closes as soon as I press a button.

Comment: What language are you using ? C#, VB ? C++ ? What extension have you installed ? Have you tried placing the connection inside a try/catch block ? Posting the code you're using to connect might help you as well. Make sure you update your question by [**clicking here**](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17170146/edit) with the relevant updates.

Comment: I installed the extension called "MySQL tools for visual studio." To create the connection I have not written any code, I simply selected tools> connect to the database and selected MySQL Database, but when I go to enter the data the window closes.

Comment: [**Have you tried via server explorer**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-visual-studio-making-a-connection.html) ? On a project ? Or only via the tools menu ?

Comment: on a project (written in c #), I tried to connect to the database with the tools menu

Answer (score -1):

I have not written in C# but in VB the connection would be:

```
Dim Mysqlconn as MySqlConnection
Mysqlconn = New MySqlConnection
Mysqlconn.ConnectionString =
            "server=yourservername;User Id=user;password=password;Persist Security Info=True;database=database name"
```

I'm sure the code would be similar. Also as Prix said i would place inside a try/catch block. as for the issue with connecting via the tool menu... did you install the MySql ODBC connectors? this might be why its closing. also check the MySql issue log because not all versions of the ODBC connector are compatible with the msql extension in visual studio 2012